# Problems building & running Openni2_camera

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, openni2-camera, openni2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I've managed to download and successfully compile OpenNi2 and run the sample apps.

Getting some problems with Openni2_camera however:

Compiling I get the likes of:

```
/home/mark/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libopenni2_wrapper.so: undefined reference to `oniStreamRegisterNewFrameCallback'
/home/mark/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libopenni2_wrapper.so: undefined reference to `oniStreamGetProperty'
/home/mark/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libopenni2_wrapper.so: undefined reference to `oniDeviceIsCommandSupported'
/home/mark/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libopenni2_wrapper.so: undefined reference to `oniDeviceSetProperty'
/home/mark/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libopenni2_wrapper.so: undefined reference to `oniReleaseDeviceList'
/home/mark/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libopenni2_wrapper.so: undefined reference to `oniStreamDestroy'
/home/mark/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libopenni2_wrapper.so: undefined reference to `oniStreamStart'
/home/mark/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libopenni2_wrapper.so: undefined reference to `oniDeviceCreateStream'
```

And probably related:

Running (or trying to)

```
rosrun openni2_camera OpenNI2.cfg
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/mark/catkin_ws/src/openni2_camera/cfg/OpenNI2.cfg", line 7, in <module>
  gen = ParameterGenerator()
 File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dynamic_reconfigure/parameter_generator_catkin.py", line 234, in     __init__
self.dynconfpath = sys.argv[1]  # FIXME this is awful
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'm running this with Groovy on my PC. Was to stick with Groovy ideally as I'm going to migrate it all to my Raspberry Pi

Many Thanks

Mark

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/151531/problems-building-&-running-openni2_camera/) by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1834 on 2014-04-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbinney](https://answers.ros.org/users/3292/jbinney/) on 2014-04-10**:
How did you install OpenNi2? The ROS debs are built from a fork of that - there may be modifications. Can you uninstall your source copy of OpenNi2 and `sudo apt-get install libopenni2-dev libopenni2-0`?

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2014-04-11**:
Okay just tried that and still getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you ever get around this?
Cheers

---

Originally posted by [dhood](https://answers.ros.org/users/18823/dhood/) with karma: 621 on 2014-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2014-08-13**:
Hi,

Sorry for the tardy reply. Yes managed to get it build. I had to download and build OpenNI2 from scrach (https://github.com/kalectro/OpenNI2) then made sure the pcl part of ros was built okay the finally built openni2_camera (https://github.com/ros-drivers/openni2_camera)

At the moment testing will let you know in the next day or so how that goes

**Comment by [miguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/21658/miguel/) on 2015-08-15**:
Did you manage to get this working? Ive installed Kalectros OpenNI2 and that is working but I can only build openni2_camera from kalectros repo which does not work with openni2_launch..is there anyway to use the ros-drivers openni2_camera? my raspbeery pi says cant find libopenni2?

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2015-08-15**:
Yes - You need to download and build OpenNI2 - It takes a while but it'll be faster on RPi2